# Adding a customer with address details to QuickBooks

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm working on a Saas and have been using Keith Palmer's PHP Dev Kit.

For the most part, it has worked really well - I can download customers, add customers and add invoices which is what I wanted to achieve.

However, when Adding the customer, I don't seem to be able to add the address and phone details. I've tried various strategies and none have worked. As I need to sync the data to some degree, I really need it to add these fields.

My Customer object is created with `$Customer = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Customer();`

I tried creating a 
`$Address = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Address()`
 and then adding with `$Customer->addAddress($Address)` after populating the address object, but still nothing.

The basic details are saved fine, but what am I doing wrong with the address?

I looked through the examples (which is how I got the basic details to save) but didn't see how to add this.

Does anyone know how to save the address details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using the newest, v3 APIs, and the latest code from GitHub, your code should look something like this:

```
        $CustomerService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer();

        $Customer = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Customer();
        $Customer->setTitle('Mr');
        $Customer->setGivenName('Keith');
        $Customer->setMiddleName('R');
        $Customer->setFamilyName('Palmer');
        $Customer->setDisplayName('Keith R Palmer Jr ' . mt_rand(0, 1000));

        // Phone #
        $PrimaryPhone = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_PrimaryPhone();
        $PrimaryPhone->setFreeFormNumber('860-532-0089');
        $Customer->setPrimaryPhone($PrimaryPhone);

        // Bill address
        $BillAddr = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_BillAddr();
        $BillAddr->setLine1('72 E Blue Grass Road');
        $BillAddr->setLine2('Suite D');
        $BillAddr->setCity('Mt Pleasant');
        $BillAddr->setCountrySubDivisionCode('MI');
        $BillAddr->setPostalCode('48858');
        $Customer->setBillAddr($BillAddr);

        if ($resp = $CustomerService->add($Context, $realm, $Customer))
        {
                print('Our new customer ID is: [' . $resp . ']');
        }
        else
        {
                print($CustomerService->lastError($Context));
        }
```

You can get the latest code here:

- [Open-source QuickBooks PHP DevKit on GitHub](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php)

It includes an example here:

- [Example of adding a customer to QuickBooks Online with PHP](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/example_app_ipp_v3/example_customer_add.php)

The methods available for the objects *exactly* mirror the XML node names that Intuit defines [in their docs](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/customer).

So, if they have a node named:

- BillAddr

Then you'll have a corresponding object:

- QuickBooks_IPP_Object_BillAddr

And if they have nodes names:

- Line1
- Line2
- City
- CountrySubDivisionCode

Then you'll have corresponding methods:

- ->setLine1($val)  and  ->getLine1()
- ->setLine2($val)  and  ->getLine2()
- ->setCity($val)  and  ->getCity()
- ->setCountrySubDivisionCode($val)  and  ->getCountrySubDivisionCode()

Comment: Thanks Keith. It appears that the problem was that I wasn't using the correct `QuickBooks_IPP_Object_BillAddr` for the address object.

It's working fine now.

Thanks for your great work with the dev kit.