# Consolibyte QuickBooks PHP Library - How Do You Start Your Connection From the QB Server?

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbfc

I've been following this guide - http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start - to get my QuickBooks 18 Enterprise edition to connect to my LAMP stack server.  I've setup all the necessary software installations and updated config files.  I am on the step:

```
Load the .QWC file into the QuickBooks Web Connector by clicking the 'Add Application' button
```

What does the Web Connector look like and how do you get to it?  I am assuming it's the **SDKTestPlus** application that is referenced on Intuit's setup website which looks like:

[image]

but I don't see an "Add Application" button on this GUI.  I followed the start menu procedure found in this Stack [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20398451/1423787) to try to open the Web Connector, but this does not bring up any results on Windows Server 2016.

Does anyone know how to proceed with the setup here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am assuming it's the SDKTestPlus application that is referenced on Intuit's setup website which looks like:

The `SDKTestPlus` thing is something totally different from the Web Connector.

First link on Google:

- https://quickbooks.intuit.com/community/Help-Articles/Set-up-QuickBooks-Web-Connector/m-p/185852#InstallQBWC

You can also run the Web Connector by choosing, from within QuickBooks:

- File > Update Web Services

Or from your "Start" menu:

- Start > Programs > QuickBooks > Web Connector
- Start > Programs > Startup > QuickBooks Web Connector